# Postfix - send to recipient and php script at the same time

Tags: postfix

I fight with a task, I need to send email via my postfix server and do some extra thing with information about recipient and sender. I tried do this by sending email to php script (http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail) but then email isn't 
delivered to the recipient. In mail.log I see "delivered via myhook service".

Is it possible to do this? bounce email to extra script and send it to recipient.

Comment: Read up on `.forward` files.

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias:

foo@bar.org: \foo@bar.org, |/my/nifty/script.php

Comment: it is pretty nice, but what if aliases is stored in DB?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. What db? the aliases file is always (eventually) converted in a db-file, but of course there std ways (newaliases) to convert its text representation into the compiled form.